# How do I unlock the Tesla in Forza 4?

Tags: forza-motorsport-4

I saw a video that the Tesla is in Forza 4, but I have no Idea how to unlock it.  Does anyone know what to do to unlock the Tesla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be part of a pre-order DLC - the Launch Bonus Car Pack.  See this [blog post](http://forzamotorsport.net/en-us/forza_garage_9-1/) on the Forza Garage

Cars included in the bonus pack:

- 2011 Tesla Roadster Sport
- 1965 Ford Mustang GT Coupe
- 1997 Lexus SC300
- 2011 Koenigsegg Agera
- 2011 RUF RGT-8

If you pre-ordered, (or perhaps bought one of the first run of copies at retail?  There's some ambiguity here) then you should have gotten a code in the box for this.  There does not appear to currently be any other way to get these cars in the game.